# Customised email alerts through MailChimp API

Tags: api, mailchimp

I am building a site that runs an automated process every 30 minutes to match up new flights with their respective user. Once this process is completed I want to email the flight details out to the respective user. However the flight info will be different for every single user with their being 0-300+ potential emails.

Is this something that the MailChimp API will allow or do? I found this page http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/how-to/transactional-campaigns.php which I am not sure if this effects me. Is the STS more suited to this? http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts/1.0/

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mandrill (which replace the STS offer). The cool thing with mandrill is that you can link it with you mailchimp account (It's a different product but it's powered by mailchimp).

Add your templates in mailchimp as usual, and hit the button "send to mandrill". Then just use the mandrill api :

http://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=send-template

You could also use the feedblock option to display custom flight for each user. You just have to provide dynamic rss feed :

http://blog.mailchimp.com/new-feed-merge-tag-options/